# Accessing Hadoop data using REST service

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am trying to update HDP architecture so data residing in Hive tables can be accessed by REST APIs. What are the best approaches how to expose data from HDP to other services?

This is my initial idea:

I am storing data in Hive tables and I want to expose some of the information through REST API therefore I thought that using HCatalog/WebHCat would be the best solution. However, I found out that it allows only to query metadata. 
[image]

What are the options that I have here?

Thank you

Comment: When you say, access hive tables, do you mean just read them like doing `SELECT * FROM mytable` , or you expect to do much more complex requests?

Comment: I will have to use filters (i.e. filter data that is in date range which means that I'd have to pass two parameters to API request - start date and end date)

Comment: I m afraid that you could not do that using hive. but if you want to retrieve the data you could use the web hdfs REST api. as a workaround you could use Spark, with spark-jobserver https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: What about WebHCat/HBase?

Comment: You mean by copying your Hive data into Hbase after that you use the REST API of HBase? I do not think it is a decent solution

Comment: I was just reading that in Hortonworks Hadoop platform once the data is copied to Hive it can be accessed from HCatalog as well

Answer (score 1):

You can very well use WebHDFS which is basically a REST Service over Hadoop.

Please see  documentation below:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

The REST API gateway for the Apache Hadoop Ecosystem is called [KNOX](https://knox.apache.org/)

I would check it before explore any other options. In other words, Do you have any reason to avoid using KNOX?

Comment: Nope, it's just that KNOX component is not currently available in cluster which I am working on

Answer (score 0):

What version of HDP are you running?
The Knox component has been available for quite a while and manageable via Ambari.

Can you get an instance of HiveServer2 running in HTTP mode?
This would give you SQL access through J/ODBC drivers without requiring Hadoop config and binaries (other than those required for the drivers) on the client machines.